# How to properly delete/release AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am implementing a video app, that lists video and able to stream or watch local videos. If I try to watch videos with my player that inherits from AVPlayer, a lot of threads initated, after 15-20 times, the system does not alloc the AVPlayer well and, even if I do not get any error, the player view is blank and nothing happening...I need to kill app to restore.

How to deal with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: This has been bugging me so much lately, I'm looking into it now, and will post something as soon as I find a solution.

Comment: did you find any solution with this @jay ?

Comment: I have similar trouble.
When setup video, and its play well, there creating "com.apple.coremedia.player.async" thread.
And if these thread count become 15+ the video don't appear. Its seems to be a limitation for AVPlayer or AVPlayerLayer. 
I'm also trying to figure out how correct dealloc those players.
Did you find some solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, in my case the AVPlayerLayer didn’t get DE allocated successfully because somehow a custom label grabbed the strong reference of controller and the controller did not get DE allocated. 
  Implement

```
deinit {

}
```

in your controller and check this called or not. If not you have the solution.
 I hope this helps.